# Solving a 2D convection and diffusion PDE with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Hello I have the following PDE, $$Pe\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}$$
and I am trying to solve it in Mathematica. In my case $Pe=2$.

Here is a snippet of the notepad I am using.

```
pde = 2 D[z[x, y], x] + 2 D[z[x, y], y] ==  D[D[z[x, y], x], x] + D[D[z[x, y], y], y]
bc1 = z[0, y] == 0
bc2 = z[1, y] == 1
bc3 = D[z[x, y], y] == 0 /. y -> 0
bc4 = D[z[x, y], y] == 0 /. y -> 1
DSolve[{pde, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4}, z[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Mathematica is not giving me a solution so I must be messing something up. I'm only interested in getting a symbolic solution to the PDE if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not messing anything up - `DSolve` does not know the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When all else fails, try FEM

```
pde = 2 D[z[x, y], x] +2 D[z[x, y], y] -D[D[z[x, y], x], x]+D[D[z[x, y], y], y];
bc1 = DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 0, x == 0];
bc2 = DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 1, x == 1];
bc3 = NeumannValue[0, y == 0];
bc4 = NeumannValue[0, y == 1];
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == bc3 + bc4, bc1, bc2}, z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement",
             "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z[x,y]"}, BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! Under Method, is it possible to use other options besides FEM? And is there any way to get an expression from Mathematica?

Comment: @NWernerC456, no FEM is the only option for stationary (elliptic) PDEs. The interpolating function is an expression; though I suspect you are looking for an analytical solution, which `NDSolve` does not give. As a side note, the `NeumannValue`s are not necessary. Neumann zero is the default.

Comment: @user21, Ok well if I can't use anything but FEM that should be fine but can I still get the data points at each node in a NxN mesh to plot in MATLAB? I'm trying to compare my numerical results to this analytic result.

Comment: @NWernerC456, `NDSolve` does not generate a analytic result. Just evaluate the interpolating function at the nodes.

Comment: @user21, OK but how do I get the interpolating function?

Comment: @NWernerC456, `sol` is the interpolating function.

Comment: @user21, is there a way I can export sol?